# KML file is not working properly in google API

Tags: html, google-maps, kml

I was mapping KMZ file to google map .
So i had two copies of a single KMZ file .. But the one which is copied is working and the original is not working .BOth the files are same

========== Copied file code ==============

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB-fWo4fKidjcdsWOEeCORH8adp8JMV-RE&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);

            var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.udayan2k12.com/shape/mmn.kmz");
            kmlLayer.setMap(map);
        }
        function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&' +
            'callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:43%; height:49%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But if i replace it

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.udayan2k12.com/shape/BMC Boundary.kmz");
            kmlLayer.setMap(map);
```

It doesnot work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URLEncode since you have a space in there -- try http://www.udayan2k12.com/shape/BMC%20Boundary.kmz